# Getting a good table and nav-bar with bootstrapmd4

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am working on an angular front end for a cloud app I am doing in my classes, and my group decided to go with angular and bootstrap. We are using SCSS for style. I am trying to fix up our nav-bar to look a bit better and to add a better table to one of our components.

This is what we have for the nav-bar

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <!-- Container wrapper -->
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Navbar brand -->
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">{{title}}</a>

    <!-- Toggle button -->
    <button class="navbar-toggler"
            type="button"
            (click)="basicNavbar.toggle()"
            aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </button>

    <!-- Collapsible wrapper -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"
         id="navbarSupportedContent"
         mdbCollapse
         #basicNavbar="mdbCollapse">
      <!-- Left links -->
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a routerLink="/my-teams">MyTeams</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a routerLink="/matches">Matches</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <!-- Left links -->
      
    </div>
    <!-- Collapsible wrapper -->
  </div>
  <!-- Container wrapper -->
</nav>
```

and this is what we have for the table

```
<table id="tableSortExample" mdbTable class="z-depth-1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let head of headElements; let i = index" aria-controls="tableSortExample" scope="col" [mdbTableSort]="elements" [sortBy]="headElements[i]">
        {{head | titlecase}}
        <mdb-icon fas icon="sort"></mdb-icon>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr mdbTableCol *ngFor="let match of matches">
      <th scope="row">{{match.teamA}}</th>
      <td>{{match.teamB}}</td>
      <td>{{match.teamAScore}}</td>
      <td>{{match.teamBScore}}</td>
      <td>{{match.winner}}</td>
      <td>{{match.completed}}</td>
      <td>{{match.gameName}}</td>
      <td>{{match.datePlayed}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Our angular app, when on the matches component looks like this
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fE444.png)
but it's not at all what we want it to look like. The nav-bar designs from [the navigation guide on the bootstrap site](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/navigation/navbar/) don't seem to work and the table [doesn't look like the demo from the same site](https://ng-demo.mdbootstrap.com/tables/sort). I just need some help to figure out where I went wrong in this

Comment: Did you follow the adding of styles to angular.json as stated here? https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/getting-started/quick-start/#npm-installation

Comment: we did but it still doesn't work. I meet up with my group tomorrow so we'll try something then

Comment: It seems like your table tag is missing the Bootstrap table class: '<table id="tableSortExample" mdbTable class="z-depth-1 table">`.

Comment: Looks like styles aren't loading completely. Also see https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/navigation/navbar/#color-schemes for more info on color scheme classes. Looks like you might need to replace bg-light with a color like indigo, green, red, etc.

Comment: I'll try to see what I can do, and we do have the table class. We followed the site for the code